# CSS blocks wrong positioning

Tags: html, css

**EDIT: I just fix it, I  had a "line-height: 1.5em;" line in the body{}. Sorry for taking your take, thanks everyone who tryed to help me.**

I'm building a form for news system on my site. I'm only using HTML/CSS, will add php later. [This is my final result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKpGR.png)
The problem are the bottom text boxes. They're 3 (posted by/nickname/date). Their position should be higher, and you can see that [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8v63P.png). It's like only the half text is in the box.
Here are my codes:

```html
<div class="news">
  <img src="img/Facebook.png" class="news-picture" alt="test" />
  <a href="#" class="news-title">Stanislav Ivanov on "How to escape from bronze"</a>
  <span class="postedby">Posted by &nbsp </span>
  <span class="nickname"><a href="#">Sunata</a> &nbsp </span>
  <span class="date">October 6, 2015</span>
</div>
```

```css
.news-picture {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  margin: 0px 12px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  float: left;
}
.news-title:link,
:visited {
  color: #0084B4;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.news {
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  height: 45px;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.news span {
  display: block;
  max-height: 14px;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.news .postedby {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: grey;
}
.news .nickname {
  color: #0084B4;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.news .date {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle and is there exist any css you don't put in here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused because the text probably has a default `line-height`.

Try giving a custom `line-height` for example: `line-height:14px`.
(Play around with this number a bit to have it how you'd like to have it)

Answer (score 0):

Its because of float, your all `span` is `float:left` and not `clear`.
You need to clear that add remove all for span-

**css -**

```
.news-picture {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  margin: 0px 12px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  float: left;
}
.news-title:link,
:visited {
  color: #0084B4;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.news {
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  height: 45px;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/*.news span {
  display: block;
  max-height: 14px;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}*/
.news .postedby {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: grey;
}
.news .nickname {
  color: #0084B4;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.news .date {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: black;
}
.clearfix:after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

**HTML-**

```
<div class="news">
  <img src="img/Facebook.png" class="news-picture" alt="test" />
  <a href="#" class="news-title">Stanislav Ivanov on "How to escape from bronze"</a>
  <div class="clearfix">
      <span class="postedby">Posted by &nbsp </span>
      <span class="nickname"><a href="#">Sunata</a> &nbsp </span>
      <span class="date">October 6, 2015</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope it will helps you.

Comment: It didn't change anything.

Comment: ohh okay, can you please add a fiddle ?

Comment: I just fix it, I had line-height: 1.5em; that bugs everything, thanks tho.

Answer (score 0):

You Add max-height Limit

```
.news span {
  display: block;
  **max-height: 14px;**
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: It's the same with or without this line.

Comment: I just fix it, I had line-height: 1.5em; that bugs everything, thanks tho.